# How to use models with conditions in asp .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working a payment API in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API.

I want to call same end point for 3 different model.
`(for this https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/spec/api-reference-0#operation/createTransaction)`
I have 3 model classes.

```
public class MyModel 
{
    // have to add, use this model if TransactionType = Payment
    public class PaymentRequest
    {
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    }

    // have to add, use this model if TransactionType = Payment
    public class Refund
    {
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    }

    // have to add, use this model if TransactionType = Payment
    public class Repeat
    {
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- If TransactionType = Refund, then use Refund model,
- If TransactionType = Payment, then use PaymentRequest model,
- If TransactionType = Repeat, then use Repeat model.`

My question is can I do all transaction with one endpoint.

i.e

MyModel

```
public class MyModel 
{
   
        public CardDetails CardDetails { get; set; }  // This class doest not have TransactionType property

    // have to add, use this model if TransactionType = Payment
    public class PaymentRequest
    {
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    }

    // have to add, use this model if TransactionType = Payment
    public class Refund
    {
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    }

    // have to add, use this model if TransactionType = Payment
    public class Repeat
    {
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("all-payment")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Payment([FromBody] MyModel payment)
{
    // result = call services with conditions
                   
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: pass in a model that has a payment type property perhaps?

Comment: `MyModel` class has some other class in it... does it have any properties? All the sub classes have only one same property `TransactionType`... how are they different?

Comment: @Chetan yes `MyModel has anthoer class `CardDetails`. That class doest not have `TransactionType`

Comment: Have you tried using Mediator pattern? Perhaps you can difine a Query<T> where T is one of your transaction classes. Did I ever tried it? No, but perhaps might work. In any case, I would recommend using mediator as it helps decoupling your system and on CQRS.